# How to create a random prize generator with percentage?

Tags: php, javascript, html

So we can say that for example, 1/20 times you will get 200 coins. and if that fails, you will get 3 coins.
or 1/2 times you will get 9 coins and so on.

Could someone please teach me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP:

```
if(rand(1,20) == 1) $prize = 200;
else $prize = 3;
```

JS:

```
if(Math.random() < 1/20) prize = 200;
else prize = 3;
```

This kind of thing is quite trivial ;)

Comment: Damn dude I don't know why I couldn't think about it this way, great!

Comment: Btw how would I be able to "seperate" them so that if I add multiple prizes it won't be like this:

User get's 1 out of 20, but he also gets 1 out of 5 so the user will recieve 30 instead of 300?

Comment: Depends on how you want to do it. You could save the drawn value, then use a series of `if` statements to divvy up the chances. Or you could do `if(rand(1,20)==1) $prize = 200; elseif(rand(1,5)==1) $prize = 30; else $prize = 3;`